# Can't install Pytorch in Pycharm terminal, Python 3.10 .win 10

Tags: pip, pytorch, pycharm

I go to pytorch site and take this

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cu113 torchvision==0.11.1+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

I have windows 10 ,Python version is 3.10 ,CUDA version is 11.5

And I get this error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> torch==1.10.0+cu113 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.0+cu113

I really struggled and tried to solve it, Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the official [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/67669) on Pytorch's Github repository.
I've tried your exact command on python 3.9.5 and it works. I believe the issue is that PyTorch is not supported by python 3.10 yet.

Downgrading to any 3.9 version of Python should solve your problem.

Comment: do you know by any chance know when pytorch will be supported by python 3.10?

Answer (score -1):

I know how this problem solves. You need to specify the python interpreter directory in the virtualenv creation line. For example python 3.9 and below. Below is the team that helped me for MacOS.

```
virtualenv -p  /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test_opencv/bin/python env
```

Flag `-p` means `-p py, --python py            interpreter based on what to create environment (path/identifier) - by default use the interpreter where the tool is installed - first found wins (default: [])` from `virtualenv -help`

You directory might be in `usr/local/bin`.
Hope this will useful.

Comment: Hi, @vasiliy-stepanov, thanks for your first answer! Unfortunately, your solution does not apply here, because the questioner is using Windows 10. So, there is no `/opt/`, `homebrew` and possibly no `miniforge`.

Comment: The path I wrote above works in my case, because python has this path.  On Win10, you must specify the path to the python interpreter, the version of which is no higher than 3.10. You will have to use python 3.9, no matter how much you would like, because the developers of pytorch have not yet made support for the version.3.10. Pytorch won't work on python 3.10 right now